# SQL Server Count number of overlaps (date ranges)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which stores vehicles and the dates they are rented out. I would like to find out if the dates overlap and the count of overlaps for a vehicle in SQL Server 2008. The result I am expecting is as follows.

```
ID  Vehicle     StartDate   EndDate     Overlap
==============================================================
1   Ford Focus  01/01/2014  31/01/2014  1
2   Ford Focus  20/01/2014  20/02/2014  1
3   Ford Focus  01/03/2014  28/03/2014  0
4   Mercedes    18/03/2014  24/03/2014  0
5   Mercedes    01/07/2014  31/07/2014  2
6   Mercedes    15/07/2014  31/07/2014  2
7   Mercedes    25/07/2014  25/08/2014  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query:

```
select *, (select count(*) from test 
           where not (v.StartDate > EndDate or v.EndDate < StartDate) 
                 and Vehicle = v.Vehicle and ID != v.ID) as Overlap
from test v
```

### [Sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c0be/1).

Comment: What is test, what is v?